# kivymd app crashes on android phone ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

My Kivy app crashes on launch on android phone.
buildozer logcat shows the following error:

```
02-21 17:09:58.777 14941 14979 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
02-21 17:09:58.777 14941 14979 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Here are my buildozer.spec requirements:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,python-dateutil,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,plyer,android,jnius,oscpy
```

As I understand, only the KivyMD depends on PIL.
The app works perfectly on my mac and WAS working before on the android phone. The error just started to occur. So, I'm really confused and would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you might already know, KivyMD depends on PIL, not Kivy. You are using the latest version of KivyMD using git in your app, which depends on `PIL`. To remove the error just add `pillow` in the `requirements` of your `buildozer.spec` file.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, but then the apk wouldn't compile, buildozer crashes.

Comment: It should work fine. Can you post the error? Did you add `PIL` or `pillow`? You should add `pillow` not `PIL`

Comment: So, when I add pillow to the buildozer.spec file I get: "raise CommandNotFound(k)
sh.CommandNotFound: cmake". I've read that there is no recipe for pillow yet. But the app was compiling and running on android like 3 days ago...

Comment: `sudo -H apt install cmake`

Comment: when running `sudo -H apt install cmake` I get: `Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`. So I've installed the cmake with binary file from the official website. But still the same error in buildozer

Comment: you shouldn't get this error. Wait are you on mac?

Comment: Yes) I've installed `cmake` with `homebrew`. And added `pillow` to `buildozer.spec`. The apk compliles, but the app still crashes on launch. Although, this time logcat doesn't show any errors. But since you've helped with the error "No PIL module" I'm gonna accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are still not getting the desired result after following the correct answer, do refer to the requirements specidied in buildozer.spec file for the KivyMD-kitchen_sink app in the repo.

This is the link -> [Kitchen_Sink_Repo](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/buildozer.spec)

**Tip**

If, after changing the `requirements` you still see your app crashing, run the following command(s)

```
buildozer android clean
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Why?

Because when buildozer installs the earlier specified requirements, it is quiet possible that it installs versions that are not matching your apps specifications. So clean it and then run.

You should now be good to go.